# How to refresh image by setTimeout, when url is getting by ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, http

I am writing a REST client to remote api. And I am using xmlHTTPRequest to get information about images.I need to refresh my images in every 30 seconds. My implementation of setTimeout function doesn't work. Anyone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code: Image.js

```
function Camera(id, name, ip, port) {
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.classList.add("camera");
button.innerHTML += "<h3>" + name + "</h3><br>";
var ismin = true;

this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.ip = ip;
this.port = port;


this.getURL = function getURL(min) {
    var url = 'http://' + ip + ":8080/api";
    return min ? url + '/miniature/' + id + '?t=' + new Date().getTime() : url + '/image/' + id + '?t=' + new Date().getTime();
};

this.appendImg = function appendImg(url) {
    button.innerHTML = "<h3>" + name + '</h3><br><img src="' + url + '"/>';
    setTimeout(appendImg(url),30000);
};

this.showElement = function showElement(url) {
    this.appendImg(url);
    var that = this;
    document.querySelector('#camera-section').appendChild(button);
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        ismin = !ismin;
        that.appendImg(that.getURL(ismin), false);

    });
};}
```

And a part of main.js:

```
function showImage(response) {
    response =  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('camera'));
    console.log(response);
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var a = response[i];
        var camera = new Camera(a.cameraId, a.name, ip, port, true);
        var curl = camera.getURL(true);
        camera.showElement(curl);
    }

}

xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        sessionStorage.setItem('camera',JSON.stringify(response));
        //console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('camera'));
        showImage(sessionStorage.getItem('camera'));
    }
};

xml.open('GET', mainUrl);
xml.send(null);
```

Comment: One (not the only) issue is `setTimeout(appendImg(url),30000);` ... the first argument to setTimeout needs to be a function, not the "result" of a function

Comment: What are the other issues?

Comment: at first glance, it would appear that every time you call `camera.showElement(curl);` it would add to the images being shown, it wouldn't replace the image that is shown - so after a while `button.innerHTML` would be flipping between images like a mad cat lady throwing cats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the comment of [Pranay Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6336512/pranay-kumar), first part of your code could be like this::

```
function Camera(id, name, ip, port) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.classList.add("camera");
    button.innerHTML += "<h3>" + name + "</h3><br>";
    var ismin = true;

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.port = port;

    this.getURL = function getURL(min) {
        var url = 'http://' + ip + ":8080/api";
        return min ? url + '/miniature/' + id + '?t=' + new Date().getTime() : url + '/image/' + id + '?t=' + new Date().getTime();
    };

    this._appendImg = function(url) {
        return function() {
             button.innerHTML = "<h3>" + name + '</h3><br><img src="' + url + '"/>';
        }
    };

    this._timerHandle = 0;

    this.appendImg = function(url) {
        if (this._timerHandle) {
            clearInterval(this._timerHandle);
        }
        this._timerHandle = setInterval(this._appendImg(url),30000);
    }    

    this.showElement = function showElement(url) {
        this.appendImg(url);
        var that = this;
        document.querySelector('#camera-section').appendChild(button);
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            ismin = !ismin;
            that.appendImg(that.getURL(ismin), false);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `setInterval(_appendImg(url),30000);` well that wont work very well either ... first argument to both setTimeout and setInterval needs to be a function, not the "result" of a function

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I modified the code a little bit and converted the function _appendImg to a closure. I hope this works.

Comment: I used that and this load images only once

Comment: setInterval periodic function should be stopped each time you modify the contents of image url. Let me modify the code accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You want refresh image every 30 seconds.

So use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function and executes it after specified time. `setInterval` executes the code continuously after specified interval

Comment: Yeah, but if you use setTimeout() recursively, it works as setInterval but better because it has error throwing

Comment: No, you can't do that. the way `setTimeout` works is if delayed a function for a particular period browser will start execute the next statement after the `setTimeout`. It wont wait until your function get executed. So instead of using `setTimeout` in a loop use `setInterval`

Comment: I apologize, i didn't notice the word recursively. You can do it recursively